# Missing required parameter 'client_id' in @react-oauth/google

Tags: next.js, google-oauth

hi i built a app with Google Auth but in my console it gives me this Error, while i think used the variable in Correct Way .

[image]

i got my 'Client id' From https://console.cloud.google.com/ and  used it like this :

```
import { GoogleOAuthProvider } from "@react-oauth/google";
import type { AppProps } from "next/app";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "../components/Navbar";
import Sidebar from "../components/Sidebar";
import '../styles/globals.css';

const MyApp = ({ Component, pageProps }: AppProps) => {
  const [isSSR, setIsSSR] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    setIsSSR(false);
  }, []);

  if (isSSR) return null;
  console.log(process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID);// it's return my Client id 
  
  return (
    <GoogleOAuthProvider clientId={`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}`}>
      <Navbar/>
      <div className="flex gap-6 md:gap-20 ">
        <div className="h-[92vh] overflow-hidden xl:hover:overflow-auto">
          <Sidebar/>
        </div>
        <div className="mt-4 flex flex-col gap-10 overflow-auto h-[88vh] videos flex-1">
          <Component {...pageProps} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </GoogleOAuthProvider>
  );
};

export default MyApp;
```

this is my @react-oauth/google version : 0.2.6
and this is how i use google Login button :

```
import React from "react";
import Image from "next/image";
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { AiOutlineLogout } from "react-icons/ai";
import { BiSearch } from "react-icons/bi";
import { IoMdAdd } from "react-icons/io";
import { GoogleLogin, googleLogout } from "@react-oauth/google";
import Logo from "../utils/tiktik-logo.png";
import { createOrGetUser } from "../utils";

const Navbar = () => {
  const User = false;
  return (
    <div
      className="w-full flex justify-between
    items-center border-b-2 border-gray-200 py-2 px-4"
    >
      <Link href={"/"}>
        <div
          className="w-[100px] md:w-[129px]
         md:h-[30px] h-[38px]"
        >
          <Image
            className="cursor-pointer"
            src={Logo}
            alt="logo"
            layout="responsive"
          />
        </div>
      </Link>
      <div className="">Search</div>
      <div className="">
        {User ? (
          <div className="">Log in</div>
        ) : (
          <GoogleLogin
            onSuccess={(response) => createOrGetUser(response)}
            onError={() => console.log("Login Failed")}
          />
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Navbar;
```

this is my createOrGetUser Function :

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
export const BASE_URL = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_BASE_URL;

export const createOrGetUser = async (response: any) => {
  const decode :{name: string, picture:string,sub:string} =jwtDecode(response.credential)
  const {name , picture , sub }=decode
  const user = {
    _id: sub,
    _type: 'user',
    userName: name,
    image: picture,
  };
  

  await axios.post(`http://localhost:3000/api/auth`, user);
};
```

I have done this operation step by step from the document and unfortunately I have no idea where the problem is. Thank you for helping me to solve this problem.
Meanwhile, I use sanity as CMS and my program is written with Next JS and this is my dependencies :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@react-oauth/google": "^0.2.6",
    "@sanity/client": "^3.3.0",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "gapi-script": "^1.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "next": "12.1.6",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "18.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "zustand": "^4.0.0-rc.1"
  },
```

Comment: did you by any chance found a solution? im having the same issue